# Looping zoom/scale by scrolling on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to loop [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daZmA/531/) so that #box2 and #box reveal themselves in a continuous loop (with infinite scroll?). In other words, each time one box fills the frame, the next one should appear in the distance...again...and again...and again...etc

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box'),
      docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

  window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
        // normalize scroll position as percentage
    var scrolled = window.scrollY / ( docHeight - window.innerHeight ),
        transformValue = 'scale('+(1-scrolled)+')';

    box.style.WebkitTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.MozTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.OTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.transform = transformValue;

  }, false);

  document.getElementById('nav').addEventListener( 'click', function(event) {
    var level = parseInt( event.target.getAttribute('href').slice(1), 10 ),
        // normalize scroll position
        scrollY = ( level / 4 ) * ( docHeight - window.innerHeight );
    // enable transitions
    box.className = 'transitions-enabled';
    // change scroll position
    window.scrollTo( 0, scrollY );
  }, false);

  function transitionEnded(event) {
    // disable transition
    box.className = '';
  }

  box.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnded, false);
  box.addEventListener( 'transitionend', transitionEnded, false);
  box.addEventListener( 'oTransitionEnd', transitionEnded, false);

}, false);
```

I'm not sure what steps to take next so that it creates a seamless loop between the two divs.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to do that in JS, but maybe when #box is hidden you can move it outside the #container (resetting it) and put #box2 inside it and switch the `var box` to the new #box2. You will probably be able to do it with transitionEnded, and playing with transformValue to know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle - it could use some polishing for sure, but just something for you to work with

http://jsfiddle.net/daZmA/520/

```html
var currentlyActiveBox = 1;
var numBoxes = 2;
var prevScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('box' + currentlyActiveBox),
      docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  
  window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
  
   var box = document.getElementById('box' + currentlyActiveBox);
        // normalize scroll position as percentage
    var scrolled = window.scrollY / ( docHeight - window.innerHeight ),
        transformValue = 'scale('+(1-scrolled)+')';
 
    /*Looks like we are turning the page - hide all boxes for now*/
    if(scrolled === 1 || scrolled === 0){
         $(".box").hide();
        }

    /*Going to the next box*/
        /*prevScroll != 0 prevents jumping between the top and the bottom*/
        if(scrolled === 1 && prevScroll != 0){
           /*Make sure that we won't go beyond the number of boxes*/
         if(currentlyActiveBox + 1 <= numBoxes){
             window.scrollTo(0, 0);
           currentlyActiveBox++;
          }
        }
        
        /*Going to the previous box*/
        if(scrolled === 0 && prevScroll != 1){
          if(currentlyActiveBox - 1 >= 1){
            window.scrollTo(0, docHeight);
            currentlyActiveBox--;
          }
        }
        
        /*Now display the currently active box back*/
        $("#box" + currentlyActiveBox).show()
        
        prevScroll = scrolled;

    box.style.WebkitTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.MozTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.OTransform = transformValue;
    box.style.transform = transformValue;
    
  }, false);
  
  function transitionEnded(event) {
    // disable transition
    box.className = '';
  }
  
  box.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEnded, false);
  box.addEventListener( 'transitionend', transitionEnded, false);
  box.addEventListener( 'oTransitionEnd', transitionEnded, false);
  
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is a little bit dirty, sorry, but it does the job.
It actually works by scrolling down only, but you can easily edit it to handle the scroll back. Probably you have to set window.scrollY to middle window and start from there, checking scroll direction.
The swap occurs when scale is 0

```
if(scale == 0){
    outer_container.appendChild(current_box);
    var older_box = current_box;
    current_box = current_box == box ? box2 : box;
    container.appendChild(current_box);
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    older_box.style.WebkitTransform = "";
    older_box.style.MozTransform = "";
    older_box.style.OTransform = "";
    older_box.style.transform = "";
}
```

between inner and outer container

```
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daZmA/527/)

Comment: Thank you very much!

I'm still pretty stumped on how to set window.scrollY to begin in the middle of the window. Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: With `window.scrollTo(x,y);`. I played a bit with the code but I was unable to make work the scroll-up. Good luck with it. A question, why not using jquery?

Comment: I am open to using jquery! I'm just not sure how to go about this the best way.